# CAP with distributed System

Tags: hadoop, nosql

When we talk about nosql distributed database system, we know that all of them fall under the 2 out of three of CAP theoram. For a distributed cluster where network failure and node failure are inevitable partition tolerance is a necessity hence leaving us to chose one from availability and consistency. So its basically CP or AP.

My questions are

1. Under which category does hadoop fall into.
2. Let's say I have a cluster with 6 nodes ABC and DEF, During a network failure let's say node A,B,C and node D,E,F are divided into two independent cluster.

   Now in a consistent and partition tolerant system (CP) model since an update in node A     wont replicate to node D the consistency of the system wont allow user to update or read data till the network is up again running, Hence making the database down.

   Whereas an Available and partition tolerant system would allow the user of node D to see the old data when update is made at node A but doesn't guarantee the user of node D of the latest data. But after some time when the network is up running again it replicates the latest data of node A into node D and hence allows the user of node D to view the latest data.

   From the above two scenarios we can conclude that In an AP model there is no scope for database going hence allowing user to write and read even during failure and promises user  latest data when the network is up again, So Why do people go for Consistent and partition tolerant model (CP). In my perspective during network failure (AP) has an advantage over (CP) allowing user to read and write data while the database under (CP) is down.
3. Is there any system that can provide CAP together excluding the concept of Cassandra's eventually consistency.
4. When does a user Choose availability over consistency and vice versa. Is there any database out there that allows user to switch its choice accordingly between CP and AP.

Thanks in advance  :)

Comment: Is is worth noting that the "2 out of 3" rule with regards to CAP theorem can be somewhat misleading. I recommend this article: http://www.infoq.com/articles/cap-twelve-years-later-how-the-rules-have-changed

Answer (score 19, accepted):

HDFS has a unique central decision point, the [`namenode`](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/NameNode). As such it can only fall in the CP side, since taking down the namenode takes down the entire HDFS system (no Availability). Hadoop does not try to hide this:

> The NameNode is a Single Point of Failure for the HDFS Cluster. HDFS is not currently a High Availability system. When the NameNode goes down, the file system goes offline. There is an optional SecondaryNameNode that can be hosted on a separate machine. It only creates checkpoints of the namespace by merging the edits file into the fsimage file and [does not provide any real redundancy](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEqQMLSXQlY).

Since the decission where to place data and where it can be read from is always handled by the namenode, which maintains a consistent view in memory, HDFS is always consistent (C). It is also partition tolerant in that it can handle loosing data nodes, subject to replication factor and data topology strategies.

> Is there any system that can provide CAP together?

Yes, such systems are often mentioned in Marketing and other non-technical publications.

> When does a user Choose availability over consistency and vice versa.

This is a business use case decision. When availability is more important they choose AP. When consistency is more important, they choose CP. In general when money changes hands the consistency takes precedence. Almost every other case favors availability.

> Is there any database out there that allows user to switch its choice accordingly between CP and AP

Systems that allows you to modify both the write and the read quorums can be tuned to be either CP or AP, depending on the needs.

Comment: Thanks for response. In HDFS the name node receives heart beats from the data node every 3 sec. During a node failure the heart beat stops coming to the name node from the affected node and name node declares the affected node as dead. The users accessing the dead node are then redirected to any of its replica node. Doesn't this concept make hadoop Available and inconsistent atlest at node level because even after a node is dead user is able to read data from a replica node.

Comment: No, because HDFS blocks are immutable. Data nodes only handle blocks, not logical entities (files). A block served by a data node cannot be inconsistent, due to immutability, and the directive to read that block can only be given by the namenode.

Comment: thanks for your response, Really appreciate it. Can You please elaborate the following                                                      "There is an optional SecondaryNameNode that can be hosted on a separate machine. It only creates checkpoints of the namespace by merging the edits file into the fsimage file and does not provide any real redundancy."                                                                                     I will also be glad if you provide some link which can enlighten me about the checkpoint of the namespaces.

Comment: Can you ask a separate question about that? Thanks.